# .NET MAUI App Binding to ImageSource isnt working

Tags: xamarin.forms, maui

Im using a Media Picker to open the photo library on my phone, when i select an image and i can step over the code and everything looks fine but the image is not set. I have no idea what is going wrong here, any thoughts would be helpful

View

```
<Border Margin="0,10,0,0"
         Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
         Stroke="{StaticResource BorderColor}"
         BackgroundColor="{StaticResource ControlLight}" >
      <Border.StrokeShape>
        <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="10" />
      </Border.StrokeShape>

      <Image HorizontalOptions="Center"
             VerticalOptions="Center"
             Aspect ="AspectFill"
             HeightRequest="80"
             Source="{Binding StoreIcon, Mode=TwoWay}"
             WidthRequest="80">
      </Image>
</Border>`
```

ViewModel

```
private ImageSource _StoreIcon;
public ImageSource StoreIcon
{
    get { return _StoreIcon; }
    set {
          if (value != null)
          {
              _StoreIcon = value;
              OnPropertyChanged();
          }
        }
}
```

```
[RelayCommand]
        async Task PickImage()
        {
            // Open file picker
            var file = await FilePicker.PickAsync(new PickOptions
            {
                PickerTitle = "Choose Product Image",
                FileTypes = FilePickerFileType.Images
            });

            // return if no file selected
            if (file == null)
                return;

            // Get stream from selected file, set ImageSource from file stream
            var stream = await file.OpenReadAsync();
            StoreIcon = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);

            // Get extension
            string[] splitArray = file.FullPath.Split('.');
            Store.IconMimeType = "." + splitArray[splitArray.Count() - 1];

            // Get b64 Image
            byte[] imageBytes = FileHelper.ReadFully(stream);
            Store.IconB64Image = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);

        }
```

I have tired using the following but the AI just generates the same code as above

[ObservableProperty]
public string _storeIcon;

Thanks for looking

Answer (score 2):

I came across this because of similar issue, and this post helped me solve my issue. Thanks Kevin!

I would like to share something I learned. The issue I had was exactly as the title says but with with a different implementation and root cause from OP. In my case, I was getting a QR code from the internet as byte[] and updating a Binded ImageSource from byte[] was not updating the image to render correctly. I don't actually have the brains to understand why it was failing in the first place, but I thought I'll share it here with the working code. It's to do with how I was using the 'using' statement with streams.

It's something to do with handling IDisposable objects and scopes, but it was odd to me.

I'm using MAUI and testing on Windows, but having XAML like so:

```xml
<VerticalStackLayout>
    <ImageButton 
        Source="{Binding QRImage}" 
        Command="{Binding UpdateQrCodeCommand}"
        HeightRequest="200"/>
</VerticalStackLayout>
```

And the ViewModel (I'm using NotifyPropertyChanged.Fody NuGet package to simplify the INotifyPropertyChanged plumbing code)

```csharp
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private IQrCodeService _qrService;

    public ImageSource QRImage { get; set; }
   
    public ViewModel (IQRCodeService service) 
    {
        _qrService = service;
    }

    public IAsyncRelayCommand UpdateQrCodeCommand => new AsyncRelayCommand(UpdateQrCodeAsync);

    private async Task UpdateQrCodeAsync()
    {
        byte[] imageBytes = await _qrService.GetQrCodeForRegistrationAsync();
        
        if(imageBytes is not null)
        {
            //using var stream = new MemoryStream(imageBytes);
            //QRImage = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream); // <--- this doesn't work

            // var stream = new MemoryStream(imageBytes);
            // QRImage = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream); // <--- this works

            QRImage = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(imageBytes)); // <--- this works
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

ok so it seems its alot easier than i thought, simply need to convert file image bytes to stream and set the source. Hope this helps someone :)

```
 [RelayCommand]
async Task PickImage()
{
    // Open file picker
    var file = await FilePicker.PickAsync(new PickOptions
    {
        PickerTitle = "Choose Product Image",
        FileTypes = FilePickerFileType.Images
    });

    // return if no file selected
    if (file == null)
        return;

    // Get byte array from file
    var byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(file.FullPath);
    StoreIcon = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(byteArray));
    
    // Get extenstion
    string[] splitArray = file.FullPath.Split('.');
    Store.IconMimeType = "." + splitArray[splitArray.Count() - 1];

    // Get b64 Image
    Store.IconB64Image = Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray);

}
```

Comment: Thank you for showing code that works. Unless you thought of this on your own, please add to answer a link to the original source. Perhaps the two lines starting at `var byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes ...` are based on the similar [open issue](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/6525)?

Comment: Why not use ImageSource.FromFile() and skip the extra step?

Comment: @jason   StoreIcon = ImageSource.FromFile(file.FullPath); works fine but in my instance i need a base64 version of the image to store in my db. Thats why i have the extra step